# Linking a simple SQLite Database using Flask

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy

I am currently trying to create an SQLite database using python.

here is my code

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////c/PStuff/friend.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class ExampleTable(db.Model):
   id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
```

I have already created a database called 'friend.db' in the PStuff folder. It is currently empty.

In cmd i used this to create the database:`sqlite3 friend.db`
I then used a python shell:`from test3 import db`

Lastly when i use:
`db.create_all()`
i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\PStuff\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2285, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
  File "c:\PStuff\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 363, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "c:\PStuff\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 773, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "c:\PStuff\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 492, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "c:\PStuff\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\impl.py", line 238, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "c:\PStuff\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 308, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "c:\PStuff\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 437, in __init__
    self.__connect(first_connect_check=True)
  File "c:\PStuff\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 657, in __connect
    pool.logger.debug("Error on connect(): %s", e)
  File "c:\PStuff\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 68, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(
  File "c:\PStuff\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 178, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "c:\PStuff\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 652, in __connect
    connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "c:\PStuff\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\strategies.py", line 114, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "c:\PStuff\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 490, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\PStuff\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 1033, in create_all
    self._execute_for_all_tables(app, bind, 'create_all')
  File "c:\PStuff\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 1025, in _execute_for_all_tables
    op(bind=self.get_engine(app, bind), **extra)
  File "c:\PStuff\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py", line 4320, in create_all
    bind._run_visitor(
  File "c:\PStuff\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2057, in _run_visitor
    with self._optional_conn_ctx_manager(connection) as conn:
  File "c:\PStuff\lib\contextlib.py", line 113, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "c:\PStuff\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2049, in _optional_conn_ctx_manager
    with self._contextual_connect() as conn:
  File "c:\PStuff\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2251, in _contextual_connect
    self._wrap_pool_connect(self.pool.connect, None),
  File "c:\PStuff\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2288, in _wrap_pool_connect
    Connection._handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection(
  File "c:\PStuff\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1554, in _handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection
    util.raise_(
  File "c:\PStuff\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 178, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "c:\PStuff\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2285, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
  File "c:\PStuff\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 363, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "c:\PStuff\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 773, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "c:\PStuff\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 492, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "c:\PStuff\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\impl.py", line 238, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "c:\PStuff\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 308, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "c:\PStuff\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 437, in __init__
    self.__connect(first_connect_check=True)
  File "c:\PStuff\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 657, in __connect
    pool.logger.debug("Error on connect(): %s", e)
  File "c:\PStuff\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 68, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(
  File "c:\PStuff\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 178, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "c:\PStuff\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 652, in __connect
    connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "c:\PStuff\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\strategies.py", line 114, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "c:\PStuff\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 490, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) unable to open database file
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

I am very new to SQL, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with Replace

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////c/PStuff/friend.db'
```

with

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///c/PStuff/friend.db'
```

based on SQLALCHEMY Documentation

```
sqlite:////db_absolute_path

sqlite:///db_relative_path
```

for windows try this thing  (if you are putting database in same dir)

```
file_path = os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())+"\\friend.db"

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///'+file_path
```

Comment: Tried that, same result im afraid!

Comment: @CallumWallace : I have updated for windows. please try that. if not work please let me know.